# Latin translation for "Forwards, into a standardized world"

Tags: classical-latin, english-to-latin-translation, motto

I'm currently doing a project for which I'd love to use some Latin phrases as mottos. One of these would be "Forwards, into a standardized world". Using some dictionaries and wild guesswork, the best I've been able to come up with is "*Procede, in normus mundus*", but I suspect that that's not correct.

Does anyone know the right translation?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Mottoes like this are a little tricky to translate, and there will not be a unique correct translation.
Here is one suggestion.

The most suitable translation that comes to mind for "forward!" is *porro!* and it is quite literal.
You can also use an imperative like *procede/procedite*, "go forward" (singular/plural), but an adverb like *porro* preserves the impersonal nature of the original.

It is not clear how to best translate "standardized".
I would work with the word *norma*, which also means "standard".
The one needs to derive "standardized" from this choice of "standard".
One can use the adjective *normalis* and derive *normalizatus*, but that does not feel very classical.
As the question is tagged [classical-latin](/questions/tagged/classical-latin), I suggest the more classical *normatus*.
More literally, *norma* means a measurement square (which can well be considered a standard) and *normatus* means "made according to the square".

Thus, my suggestion is:

> *Porro, in mundum normatum!*